# How to let fluentd to collect logs from a container outside of k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, fluentd

I have an EFK (ElasticSearch, Fluentd, Kibana) being deployed in a Kubernetes cluster. I can get the logs from pods in the cluster.

However, I have a container which is outside of the cluster (at different server; running using Docker), and I want to use Fluentd to collect the logs of this container.

I know the easiest way is to deploy this container inside the current Kubernetes cluster. But due to some design considerations, I have to put this container outside of the Kubernetes cluster.

Is there any way to let the current Fluentd to collect logs from the container which is outside of the Kubernetes cluster? Any setting that I have to do at Fluentd?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In Kubernetes, containerized applications that log to stdout and stderr have their log streams captured and redirected to JSON files on the nodes. The Fluentd Pod will tail these log files, filter log events, transform the log data, and ship it off to the Elasticsearch cluster we deployed earlier.

Log collection problem from docker containers inside the cluster. We will do so by deploying fluentd as DaemonSet inside our k8s cluster.

In addition to container logs, the Fluentd agent will tail Kubernetes system component logs like kubelet, Kube-proxy, and Docker logs. To see a full list of sources tailed by the Fluentd logging agent, consult the kubernetes.conf file used to configure the logging agent.

Follow this [doc](https://blog.opstree.com/2019/12/17/collect-logs-with-fluentd-in-k8s-part-2/) for more information.